# check if something is a number, in a function with an if statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, numbers

I want a function to take two parameters, and if they are both numbers to tell me which is bigger. i also want it to give a nice output if they are some of them are not numbers (beacause it won't be able to calculate it anyway).

I've got to the point where it is able to handle int, but not floats. it got over my head and I'm wondering what would be the best practice to write that down.

here is what I got so far;

```
var iamanumbergenius = function(a, b) {
if (Number.isInteger(a) && Number.isInteger(b)) {
if (a > b) {
  console.log('first is greater');
  } else if (b > a) {
  console.log('second is greater');
  } else {
  console.log('equality is the answer');
  }
} else { console.log('i only like nums'); }
}
```

sorry for ugly code, brought right out of chrome dev tools, where there's no such thing as hitting the enter with out anxiety XD

pretty sure I'm missing some method or typeof thing... maybe with some more boolean operatos and also number.isfloat?
in that case I'm not sure what comes before what in term of order of operations: || and the &&..

thanks! I'm really new to that stuff so any help would be great :)

Comment: If the `a` and `b` are already numbers, `typeof a === 'number'` would return true for integers or floats.

Comment: `typeof value == 'number'` tends to work pretty well. Noting that *NaN* is type number too. `value % 1 === 0` also works for integer.

Comment: try isNaN() to check if is a number and not if it's only an integer.

Comment: Do you want to check for numbers or integers only? Because the title tells numbers but code example integers.

Comment: @Taplar thanks! turned out I have simply forgotten to put the ''... silly 01:30 me

Answer (score 1):

Because `typeof` returns `number` for both integers and floats, you can use that for your function.

Demonstration of `typeof`:

```js
console.log(typeof 1.3);
```

Here's how you implement it in your function:

```
if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number')
```

Also, because `typeof NaN === 'number', you should use`isNaN()`in your`if` statement too:

```
if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && !(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)))
```

Comment: Note that `typeof NaN == 'number'`.

Comment: Good point @RobG, I'll include `isNaN()` as well. Thanks for picking up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(isNaN(123));
console.log(isNaN(1.23));
console.log(isNaN('stack'));
```